# extract Json file to decode in base64

Tags: python, json, base64

with respect,
I am trig to use the contents of a json file which is encoded with base64.
I would like to decode the encoded part of the json file. following is my code.

```
response={"response": [{"objcontent": [{"rowkeys":["time","lat","lon","tos"],"rowvalues": [["AAAAAAAALkA=","AAAAAADgU8A=","AAAAAAAA8D8=","7HitYA"],["AAAAAAAALkA=","AAAAAADgU8A=","AAAAAAAACEA=","7HitYA"],["AAAAAAAALkA=","AAAAAADgU8A=","AAAAAAAAFEA=","7HitYA"]]}]}]}

import base64
import struct
for response_i in response['response']:
    a=base64.b64decode(response_i['objcontent'][0]['rowvalues'])
    struct.unpack('12d',a)
```

following is the error which i got.

```
TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'list'
```

May someone give some tips to overcome this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Reread the error message.

Comment: You have a **list of lists** with strings, not a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in your whole list, which itself contains more lists:

```
>>> response_i['objcontent'][0]['rowvalues']
[['AAAAAAAALkA=', 'AAAAAADgU8A=', 'AAAAAAAA8D8=', '7HitYA'], ['AAAAAAAALkA=', 'AAAAAADgU8A=', 'AAAAAAAACEA=', '7HitYA'], ['AAAAAAAALkA=', 'AAAAAADgU8A=', 'AAAAAAAAFEA=', '7HitYA']]
```

You'd need to decode *each separate entry*, not the whole list:

```
for response_i in response['response']:
    for row in response_i['objcontent'][0]['rowvalues']:
        for encoded_obj in row[:-1]:
            decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded_obj)
```

Note that I *ignore* the last value in the row, that's not a Base64 value.

Your *next* problem is that your Base64 data doesn't contain enough bytes to hold 12 float values (each 8 bytes, so you'd need 96 bytes). Since they are *8 bytes* each, you probably have just *one* floating point value in each string.

So you'd want to decode just the one float:

```
floating_point_value = struct.unpack('d', decoded)[0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> for response_i in response['response']:
...     for row in response_i['objcontent'][0]['rowvalues']:
...         for encoded_obj in row[:-1]:
...             decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded_obj)
...             print(struct.unpack('d', decoded)[0])
...
15.0
-79.5
1.0
15.0
-79.5
3.0
15.0
-79.5
5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json seems to be malformed, there are more opening [ than closing ]. So I can't give you an exact breakdown.

In any event, the value that matches the key 'rowvalues' is a list of lists [ [], [], [] ]. So you need to break it down accordingly to pass the correct values to the decoder

```
for value_list in response_i['objcontent'][0]['rowvalues']:
    for value in value_list:
        # enter your decode code here
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the base64 decoding, the struct.unpack fails for me.

```
import base64
import struct

response = {
    "response": [{
        "objcontent": [{
            "rowkeys": ["time", "lat", "lon", "tos"],
            "rowvalues": [
                ["AAAAAAAALkA=", "AAAAAADgU8A=", "AAAAAAAA8D8=", "7HitYA"],
                ["AAAAAAAALkA=", "AAAAAADgU8A=", "AAAAAAAACEA=", "7HitYA"],
                ["AAAAAAAALkA=", "AAAAAADgU8A=", "AAAAAAAAFEA=", "7HitYA"]
            ]
        }]
    }]
}


for response_i in response['response']:
    for r in response_i['objcontent'][0]['rowvalues']:
        for item in r[:-1]: # last item doesnt seem to be be base64 encoded !
            a = base64.b64decode(item)
            print a
            # .... whatever ... struct.unpack('12d',a)
```